# C# how do i return an environment variable as a string

Tags: c#, string, environment-variables

in C#, I want to get the list of environment variables, and turn them into strings. however, when I exectute the code, I get error:

Embedded statement cannot be a declaration or labeled statement

at string teststring = de.Value;

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;

class Sample
{

public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("GetEnvironmentVariables: ");
    foreach (DictionaryEntry de in Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables())
        string teststring = de.Value;
        string testpath = String.Format("\nValue as string: ",teststring);
        Console.WriteLine(testpath);
        Console.WriteLine("\n  {0} = {1}", de.Key, de.Value);       
}
}
```

how can I fix this, and why is this error occurring?

Comment: you are missing `{}`

Comment: Thank you! if I commented out the problematic lines, the foreach statement worked without the {}. odd, but it fixed it!

Comment: If you are doing only 1 instruction in foreach, then you don't need the braces, but can't be a declaration (in your case `string teststring = de.Value;`)

Answer (score 1):

You need put `{` and `}` around your `foreach` block, because :

1. You have 2 variables declaration
2. You have more than 1 line of statement

---

```
public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("GetEnvironmentVariables: ");
    foreach (DictionaryEntry de in Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables())
    {
        string teststring = de.Value;
        string testpath = String.Format("\nValue as string: ",teststring);
        Console.WriteLine(testpath);
        Console.WriteLine("\n  {0} = {1}", de.Key, de.Value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working version and got rid of the extra formating that could be simplified. You have also forgot the '{0}' in the String format

```
public static void Main()
{
   Console.WriteLine("\nGetEnvironmentVariables: ");
   foreach (DictionaryEntry de in Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables())
   {
       Console.WriteLine("\nValue as string: {0}",de.Value);
       Console.WriteLine("\n\t{0} = {1}", de.Key, de.Value);
   }
}
```